# Combine ActiveCell.Value and Characters to search file

Tags: string, excel, vba, search

I'm trying to hyperlink quote names in a workbook to the location of the files. Not all of the files are present, I would like to test against a boolean to see if they exist before creating the hyperlink. I have been using the filename from active cell to retain a string and search. The naming convention is 'XX-MMDDYY.XX. Saved files are under the name Quote_XX-MMDDYY.XX. I have combined "Quote_" wit the active cell to search for the file, but my macro only seems to loop through the list.

```
Sub LoopRange()

    Dim currRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim ws As String, quoteID As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim FileName As String
    path = "C:\Some file path\"

    ws = "Quote LOG"
    currRow = 3
    lastRow = Sheets(ws).Cells(Sheets(ws).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    While currRow <= lastRow
        Sheets(ws).Cells(currRow, 1).Select
        quoteID = "Quote_" & ActiveCell.value
        FileName = path & quoteID
        If Dir(FileName) <> "" And quoteID <> "" Then
            Sheets(ws).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(currRow, 2), Address:=FileName, TextToDisplay:=quoteID
        End If
        currRow = currRow + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: You need another backslash at the end of the path variable. `path = "C:\Some file path\"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did MacroMan's tip help?  If not, let me know and I'll take a crack.

One thing though, that is very good to learn for VBA, is how to (avoid .Activate and .Select)[[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros]).  I have tweaked your code with this in mind, it should run a little smoother:

```
Sub LoopRange()

Dim currRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
Dim ws As String, quoteID As String
Dim path          As String
Dim FileName      As String
Dim cellValue     As String

path = "C:\Some file path\"

ws = "Quote LOG"
currRow = 3
lastRow = Sheets(ws).Cells(Sheets(ws).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

While currRow <= lastRow
    'Sheets(ws).Cells(currRow, 1).Select
    cellValue = Sheets(ws).Cells(currRow, 1)
    'quoteID = "Quote_" & ActiveCell.Value
    quoteID = "Quote_" & Sheets(ws).Cells(currRow, 1)
    Debug.Print quoteID
    FileName = path & quoteID & ".pdf"
    If Dir(FileName) <> "" And quoteID <> "" Then
        Sheets(ws).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(currRow, 2), Address:=FileName, TextToDisplay:=quoteID
    End If
    currRow = currRow + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it did to define the path. For a while I just had it looping through afterwards

Comment: Thank you for the foresight NOT to use Active cell!

Comment: @PeaButter - Thanks, it's such a great thing to learn when starting VBA.  Also, you could skip the entire "cellValue" variable, as it's not used anywhere.  I edited it to show how to get around `.select` and `.activate`, but you could also have used `quoteID = "Quote_ " & cellValue`.  Otherwise, that variable could be commented/deleted out.

Comment: I've ran it a couple times (with an incomplete database), it is much more robust than active cell.

Comment: @PeaButter, it's working correctly, yeah?  One way to speed it up too, is to add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning, under the declared values, and then `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end, before `End Sub`.

Comment: I'll give that a whirl too, sometime this morning. I'll keep you posted and let you know how it works out.

Comment: @PeaButter - how'd it go? Any comments or suggestions for code improvement?

Comment: I didn't get a chance until lunch to get into that macro. This did update more robustly, I never got a "Not Responding" on the header of the workbook as this Macro ran. Apologies for the delayed response!

Answer (score 0):

My filenames were a mismatch from the code. I needed to add "Quote_" to quoteID and the filetype, in this case ".pdf" to FileName

**
Sub LoopRange()

```
Dim currRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
Dim ws As String, quoteID As String
Dim path As String
Dim FileName As String
path = "C:\Users\pxbotr\Documents\Quote DataBase\"

ws = "Quote LOG"
currRow = 3
lastRow = Sheets(ws).Cells(Sheets(ws).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

While currRow <= lastRow
    Sheets(ws).Cells(currRow, 1).Select
    quoteID = "Quote_" & ActiveCell.Value
    FileName = path & quoteID & ".pdf"
    If Dir(FileName) <> "" And quoteID <> "" Then
        Sheets(ws).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(currRow, 1), Address:=FileName, TextToDisplay:=quoteID
    End If
    currRow = currRow + 1
Wend
```

End Sub

**

Comment: One way to shorten the code, albeit a little, is to chage `ws = "quoteLog"` and do `dim ws As Worksheet` then `Set ws = Sheets("Quote LOG")` then in the later code you can just do `lastRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, ...` and `ws.Hyperlinks.add ...`